# ¿Cómo conectar Delphi con base de datos MySQL?

Tags: mysql, windows, delphi

**Configuración del Equipo:**

Base de datos MySQL versión 5.5.16 (Instalada con XAMPP)

Delphi 7

Windows 7 Enterprise (64 bits)

**Procedimiento seguido:**

Descargar e instalar Driver ODBC MySQL (mysql-connector-odbc-noinstall-5.3.4-winx64 ) (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/)

Crear origen de datos en Windows. (Panel de Control / Herramientas Administrativas / Orígenes de datos ODBC)

1. Elegir MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver
2. Configurar parámetros de conexión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Probar conexión en Delphi 7

Al momento de configurar la cadena de conexión en un formulario de Delphi utilizando ADOQuery, me permite seleccionar correctamente el origen de datos. Pero me arroja el siguiente error al probar la conexión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**“Error en la prueba de conexión al iniciar al proveedor. Error no especificado”**

¿Necesito configurar algo más para poder conectarme a la base de datos?

Comment: Delphi 7 tiene casi 15 años, ¿sigues usando esa versión, o te refieres a Delphi XE7?

Comment: Si, sigo usando Delphi 7

Comment: Delphi 7 es una aplicación de 32 bits. Por tanto, aunque tu servidor sea de 64 bits, debes utilizar el stack de conexión de 32 bits. Es decir, driver ODBC de 32 bits, ODBC manager de 32. Y ya con eso podrás establecer conexión utilizando componentes de conexión ADO.

Comment: Eso también es cierto para las aplicaciones que produzcas, pues con versiones antiguas de Delphi, como las 7, solamente se podía compilar aplicaciones de 32 bits.

Comment: Ok, voy a probar cambiando mi conector ODBC de 64 bits por 32 Bits (mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-win32.msi)

Comment: No es suficiente, solo instalar el conector ODBC de 32 bits ("Orígenes de datos ODBC" no reconoce el driver), tal como lo dices @jachguate, pues el ODBC manager es de la misma arquitectura del SO (64 bits). ¿Puedo descargar solo el ODBC manager de 32bits, o debo cambiar todo el S.O?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Otra opción  para conectar a `MySQL` (y posiblemente con mayor rendimiento que utilizar `ODBC`) es utilizar los componentes `ZeosLib`.

Los puedes [descargar desde Sourceforge aquí](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/).

Un saludo.

Comment: Componente compilado e instalado. se configura conexión utilizando Zconecction y se accede a la base de datos MySQL exitosamente.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, según describiste los pasos están bien. Recuerdo que en *Windows 7*,  *Delphi 7* daba algunos errores inexplicables si no la abrías con permiso de administrador, así que si no lo has hecho prueba. Te dejo un video que hice en el 2010 donde explico los pasos para hacer la conexión de [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) con *Delphi 7* para que revises:
[Ver Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AxdkDlhcv84)

¡Saludos!